# Vagrant Berkshelf - Shelf Path?

Tags: plugins, vagrant, berkshelf

Is it possible to set the path where the berkshelf plugin puts the cookbooks it installs? (As in the .berkshelf folder)

I am running Windows 7.

I am currently trying to install a mysql server using an opscode cookbook to a vm and here at work they have the %HOMEDRIVE% system variable set to a network drive. So when .berkshelf starts at the beginning of the Vagrantfile, it pushes the cookbooks to the network drive and it causes it to be slow and well, its not where it should be. Is there a fix to this?

VirtualBox did this as well, but I fixed it by altering the settings. I tried looking for some sort of equivalent settings for berkshelf, but the closest I got was for the standard berkshelf (thats not a vagrant plugin), it appears you can set this environment variable:

**ENV['BERKSHELF_PATH']**

Found here:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/RiotGames/berkshelf/Berkshelf#berkshelf_path-class_method

I need to be able to have the cookbooks it reads from the berksfile store to my laptops local drive instead, as in my scenario I cannot have the mobility of the VM limited to the building because of files that are stored on the network.

Any incite would be much appreciated.

Perhaps its better to use the actual berkshelf over the vagrant plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the portability - a full chef-repo ready for `chef-solo` runs, better off using standalone berkshelf instead of the `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin - which is NOT that flexibly.

For complex cookbooks, I prefer to use standalone berkshelf as it allows me to do `berks install --path chef/cookbooks` to copy all cookbooks required from `~/.berkshelf/cookbooks`, then I can just tar the whole thing and transfer to other machines for the same `chef-solo` run. some people use capistrano automate the tar and scp/rsync over the network. I just use rysnc/scp;-)

HTH

Comment: So I take it basically the answer is no, you cant. Well, thats okay. I will look into using the normal berkshelf and maybe not even using it at all. It might save some time and stress, because now when I set the berksfile path in the vagrantfile, I get a permission denied to read it. Oh well, thanks for your input! :) I shall investigate!